# Server/Client application TimeoutError on LAN

Tags: python, sockets, networking, lan

I have two programs: server.py and client.py. I need to be able to use server.py in my main PC, and client.py from my laptop. When I run them, I get the following error from client.py:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```

I have disabled firewalls in both my PC (that runs Windows 7) and my laptop (that runs Windows 8).

How do I get them to connect?

Some things that I have tried:

- Creating Firewall port rules, on the PC.
- Disabling the firewall in both computers.
- Using different ports.
- Changing the server address from "localhost" to socket.gethostname(), this changes the error from `TimeoutError` to `ConnectionRefusedError`.

The IP for my PC is 192.168.0.2, and I am sure of this because I have an Apache server running in port 80, and that one works (I can access that from my laptop).

Python versions: PC: 3.5.2, Laptop: 3.4.1

### Code

server.py:

```
import socket
import threading

server_port = 2569
server_address = "localhost"

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client_info):
        super(ClientThread, self).__init__()
        self.client_info = client_info

    def run(self):
        socket = self.client_info[0]
        bytes_received = socket.recv(100)
        print(bytes_received.decode("utf-8"))

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((server_address, server_port))
server_socket.listen(5)

while True:
    new_client = server_socket.accept()
    ClientThread(new_client).run()
```

client.py:

```
import socket

server_port = 2569
server_address = "192.168.0.2"

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.connect((server_address, server_port))
server_socket.send(b"message")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `localhost` or `socket.gethostname()` in the `server.py/client.py` scripts to the actual **internal ip** address of the server. Then it will work!

If you want to learn more why this happens I recommend reading [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/196893/difference-between-localhost-and-the-ip-address)
which explains in deep the differences between `localhost/127.0.0.1` and the `internal ip` of a machine, which are falsely considered to be the same thing, but in fact they are not.

Comment: How do I find the internal ip, then?

Comment: @sempiedram  what os are you using? Actually if you are using your PC as the server in your post you mentioned it has an internal IP `192.168.0.2` - this is the internal ip....

Comment: @sempiedram I tried out your scripts, and they executed successfully after changed from `localhost` to my internal ip address. With `localhost` I had the same error too...

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah, I was sure I had already tried using 192.168.0.2 for the server, but it gave me an error, or something. But it's working now! Thanks.

Comment: @sempiedram ,this was a great question cause it proves-shows practically in a great way that `localhost` and the `internal ip` are two different things

Comment: Yeah, I actually didn't know that, TILed. Thanks again.