# The console hint that net::ERR_CONNECTION_RES

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

[This is the screenshot of the video .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzQEj.png)#   This little program serves as a server. I make it with python.

```
import socket


def RunServer(environ, start_response):
    start_response=('200 OK',[('Content-Type','application/x-javascript')])
    data = "callback({name:'Eric',age:20,gender:'men'})"
    return data

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 80
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
print 'The server is listening'
conn,addr = s.accept()
print 'The server is connected by', addr
conn.sendall(RunServer(111,11))
while True:
    print '123'
```

## Ajax . the function of  this code is to request the information we need.

But when I ran the program , there is nothing wrong with the server. And the server did response and send the message which was data. So I believe the main problem is that I must have made a mistake when I use Ajax.

```
$(function(){
            $('#request').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'http://127.0.0.1:80',
                        cache: false,
                        async: true,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                        success:function(data){
                            alert('123');
                            $('#result').append(data.name);
                        }
                        });
            })
            function callback(arg){
                alert(arg);
                return arg;
            }


        } )
```

## solution

### server.py

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import application

httpd = make_server('127.0.0.1',80,application.RunServer)
print "Serving HTTP on port 80..."
httpd.serve_forever()
```

### application.py

```
def RunServer(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK',[('Content-Type','application/x-javascript')])
    data = "callback({name:'Eric',age:20,gender:'men'});"
    return data
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE8WR.png)

Comment: Is there a reason for you to write your own http server instead of using something existing? (like flask dev server, or nginx with wsgi)

Comment: Your are not implementing a http server. Consider using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org). Good for beginners…

Comment: could you try change from `localhost` to the **internal ip** of the server. I gave a similar answer to a similar question-problem yesterday, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925658/server-client-application-timeouterror-on-lan/39925933#39925933  - it may solve your issue ...

Comment: @coder yesterday The link you gave about the problem you solved was totally different . There were two things I want to complete. The first was that I just wanted to imitate a server which could response and send data with python . And the other one was  that I wanted to use ajax in browser to request  data from the server . And the problem was that the server did send the data, but it seemed that there were something wrong with my ajax scripts.  Sorry, I am not good at using stackoverflow.

Comment: @Loïc yesterday Actually I guess that's not the real reason . Because I just watched the video online and tried to do the same thing. And most of the code are similar to the code on the video . Unfortunately, I just couldn't  get the original code and this is just part of it.

Comment: @Loïc  I have added a picture to show the code .

Comment: Problem has been fixed. I have found the solution.  I should have imported the module `from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server` and used it to make a server.